# Can't get to /admin

Tags: forms

First time using Drupal. It's a friend's site that her former developer stopped hosting because he couldn't afford his server and gave her the public_html zip and an .sql file on a flash drive, she gave it to me and I assumed it would be as simple as turning on mod_rewrite, importing the database and uploading the files. I did this with ease, site displays fine except no form submissions of any kind work and the only console error I get is some cdn hosted file missing. After some reading, I go to http://dkmcosmetics.com/admin and I get a 403 access denied page, so then I go to http://dkmcosmetics.com/user/login and there's a login page, the form submission doesn't work on there either(just refreshes page after submission). Check folder permissions on the server, double check the settings.php, made sure there's no "cookie domain" and still no luck. Can anyone pinpoint where my problem may lay?

Comment: Is it a Drupal 6 site? If so, make sure there's a record for the anonymous user (id 0) in the `users` table.

Comment: What is the HTTP response status after you try to login on to `/login`?

Answer (score 0):

If the database dump they gave you is corrupt, or missing sensitive information (such as the users table), you may need to do some work.

Have you tried installing this "site" on a local environment first? You can, for example, download Drupal core from Drupal.org, install it as you normally would any Drupal site, and after making sure it works - you could: 1) copy the modules in the zipped or tarred file they gave you to your local install, and 2) import the database they gave you on top of the database you already installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a second answer. Do you have drush installed on the server? If not, you probably should ;)

Drush can help you with situations like this. You can do `drush status` on your site to double check your settings.php. You can also use `drush upwd` to change the password of the admin user, and `drush uli` to provide you with a one-time login link. If `upwd` or `uli` do not provide a fruitful result, then you may really have either a corrupt database (see my original answer) - or you simply may have server/LAMP issues (such as bad system permissions, Apache or PHP config issues, etc.)